# Adding selected radio button that is in a group box in a listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, radiobuttonlist

I have a group box with various radiobuttons and my goal is to add a selected item in the group box to the listbox.

This is probably not the most efficient way however, how I have this set up right now is that I created a List letters so that when a specific radiobutton is checked, the item is added into the List letters. Then, using this list items, I want to add it into the listbox whenever a button is clicked.

This is what I have started to populated the List letters:

```
private List<string> AddAllGrades()
{
    if (radA.Checked)
    {
        //add the checked radiobutton into List<int> letGrade
        allGrades.Add("A");
    }
    else if (radB.Checked)
    {
        //add the checked radiobutton into List<int> letGrade
        allGrades.Add("B");
    }
    else if (radC.Checked)
    {
        //add the checked radiobutton into List<int> letGrade
        allGrades.Add("C");
    }
    else if (radD.Checked)
    {
        //add the checked radiobutton into List<int> letGrade
        allGrades.Add("D");
    }
    else if (radF.Checked)
    {
        allGrades.Add("F");
    }
    return allGrades;
}
```

Adding the elements of allGrades whenever there's a change in group box event:

```
private void gbGrade_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radA.AutoCheck = true;
    radB.AutoCheck = true;
    radC.AutoCheck = true;
    radD.AutoCheck = true;
    radF.AutoCheck = true;
    lstDetail.Items.AddRange(allGrades.ToArray());
}
```

Adding the elements of group box to the listbox:

```
private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*if grades and credits are not selected, Error Message:
        * MessageBox.Show("A grade must be selected.");
        * MessageBox.Show("Credit hours must be selected.");
    */
    if (!(radA.Checked || radB.Checked || radC.Checked ||
        radD.Checked || radF.Checked))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("A grade must be selected.");
    }           

    if (cboCreditHrs.SelectedIndex == -1)//if" no credit is selected
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Credit hours must be selected.");
    }
    else
    {
        lstDetail.Items.AddRange(AddAllGrades().ToArray());
    }
```

Note: at the moment, the third method is not completely functional. I'm sure there is also a more efficient way of doing this but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm also trying to merge this list of grades into another list so that it's elements can be inputted into the listbox in a more appeasing format.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I think my syntax in the gbGrade_Enter is incorrect.  Also, the selected radio button does not clear out after each item is  checked.

Comment: Also, I'm sure there's a better way to add a radio button selection into a listbox without having to create multiple methods as I have shown?

Comment: Why do you need a list of strings? every time only one `radbutton` can be selected so you will add one letter to your listbox every time you press the `btnEnter`.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm adding the list grades, it is returning a symbol referrencing the location of the item not the actual value I am trying to return.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you need list for radio buttons but if you have to i think you can use this instead. Of course if your radioaButtons contains only the letter (A,B,C,D) etc.

```
private List<string> AddAllGrades()
    {
    foreach (RadioButton rad in groupBox1.Controls)
                {
                    if (rad.Checked)
                        allGrades.Add(rad.Text);
                }
                return allGrades;
    }
```

if not you can put the letter in tag property and change rad.Text to rad.Tag.ToString()